# Simplifing big imports to short

Tags: python

I am working on python application with following structure.

```
proj/
  - __init__.py
  - pkg_one/
      - __init__.py
      - module_a.py
      - module_b.py
  - pkg_two/
      - __init__.py
      - module_c.py
      - sub_pkg_two/
          - __init__.py
          - module_d.py
              - class D
          - module_e.py
              - class E
  - foo.py
```

currently to use in `foo.py` or other `pkg_one`, I am accessing like this

```
from proj.pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_d import D
from proj.pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_e import E
```

I am trying to make it more simple to access like

```
from proj.sub_pkg_two import D
from proj.sub_pkg_two import E
```

I did tried editing `__init__.py` at various levels by setting different possible paths or ways but none worked.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Import `D` and `E` in `sub_pkg_two` (in its `__init__.py` file); that makes them available from that subpackage.

Comment: "by setting different possible paths": don't do that. Packages shouldn't set things like PATH or PYTHONPATH; that should be up to the user.

Comment: Hi 9769953, No I am not touching `PATH or PYTHONPATH`. I am just editing `__init__.py` files only. I did tried that in `sub_pkg_two/__init__.py` but I still need to use `from proj.pkg_two.sub_pkg_two import E`. I am trying to skip or bypass `pkg_two`, is it possible?

Comment: You can also import `E` in `pkg_two`, or even in `proj`'s `__init__.py`. In the latter case, it's just `from proj import E` in `foo.py`.

Comment: Do you really have/want a package named `proj` that contains a module named `foo.py`, or is `foo.py` a script that happens to be in a directory named `proj` along with two top-level packages `pkg_one` and `pkg_two`? (Unrelated to your actual question, by the way...)

Comment: Hi chepner, I do have `project` directory under which is everything but rest names are dummy to simulate project structure.

Comment: Hi TomServo, Thanks. This post explained well.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by creating `proj/sub_pkg_two/__init__.py` with the following contents:

```py
from .pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_d import D
from .pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_e import E
```

However, I highly recommend against that because your package will end up with two directories with the same name, which makes it very confusing.

One way to deal with this is to edit `proj/__init__.py` with:

```py
from .pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_d import D
from .pkg_two.sub_pkg_two.module_e import E
```

Then you can import the classes as follow:

```py
from proj import D
from proj import E
```

Comment: Hi Hai, can you please explain more or shed some light on first example(not to use proj/sub_pkg_two/__init__.py) and second example (to use proj/__init__.py)